# regex: If "/" is found in line, Ingore string up until "/" and match everything after

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm new to all this, so apologies for any inaccuracies.

I'm trying to write a regex that looks for "/" in a line at a specific position. If it is found, it should ignore everything before and match everything after.

So far, I've come up with

```
^(?(?=^.{6}[\/])[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+|\n)
```

but it seems to be doing the exact opposite; if "/" is found at the 7. position, it matches everything before "/". I got inspired by different threads, yet I'm still unable to make it work.

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to match the whole string if there is no `/`? Maybe `^(?:.{6}\/\K)?.*`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/68ES47/1).

Comment: If there is no `/`, line should be ignored. I didn't know about the existence of \K, it seems to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern `^(?(?=^.{6}[\/])[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+|\n)` uses an if clause, where in the if part there is an assertion for 6 characters followed by a `/`

The assertion is at the start of the string, and does not consume characters. If that assertion is true, then match either `[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+` or a newline, so the consuming parts starts there and that is why you get that match.

It matches the first 6 characters and not the `/` because that is not in the character class.

---

You can use a capture group to match all allowed characters after the `/` at the 7th position.

```
^.{6}\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.{6}\/`  Match 6 characters and `/`
- `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)` Capture **group 1**, optionally match any of the listed in the character class

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rI5DWa/1)

Or [if supported](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) you can use `\K` to forget what is matched so far:

```
^.{6}\/\K[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.{6}\/` Match 6 characters and `/`
- `\K` Clear the match buffer (forget what is matched until now)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*` Optionally match any of the listed in the character class

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KugQWt/1)

Comment: The second solution looks interesting, but what do you mean by "if supported"? When or where is it not supported?

Comment: @RezaSaadati See this page https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html